# Installing openambit on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-installation, compiling

My question is in regards to installing openambit which is software for Suunto's ambit watch.

I followed the installation instructions [here](http://openambit.org/installation/) but it didn't work.

When I did:

```
$ mkdir libambit-build
$ cd libambit-build
$ cmake ../src/libambit
$ make
Optionally:
$ sudo make install
```

Everything went fine, but when I ran the `make` step:

```
$ mkdir openambit-build
$ cd openambit-build
$ cmake ../src/openambit
$ make
Optionally:
$ sudo make install
```

I was told:

```
dustin@dustin:~/openambit-build$ sudo cmake ~/Desktop/openambit-0.2/src/openambit/-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - found
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found.
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found.
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found.
-- Found Qt4: /usr/bin/qmake (found version "4.8.1")
-- Found libambit: /usr/local/include, /usr/local/lib/libambit.so
-- Found UDev: /usr/include 
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.3.4")
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/dustin/openambit-build
dustin@dustin:~/openambit-build$ sudo make
[  2%] Generating movescount/moc_movescountxml.cxx
[  4%] Generating ui_mainwindow.h
[  6%] Generating ui_settingsdialog.h
[  9%] Generating ui_confirmbetadialog.h
[ 11%] Generating qrc_resources.cxx
[ 13%] Generating moc_mainwindow.cxx
[ 16%] Generating moc_devicemanager.cxx
[ 18%] Generating moc_settingsdialog.cxx
[ 20%] Generating moc_settings.cxx
[ 23%] Generating moc_logstore.cxx
[ 25%] Generating moc_udevlistener.cxx
[ 27%] Generating moc_confirmbetadialog.cxx
[ 30%] Generating moc_single_application.cxx
[ 32%] Generating movescount/moc_movescount.cxx
[ 34%] Generating movescount/moc_movescountjson.cxx
[ 37%] Generating movescount/moc_movescountlogdirentry.cxx
Scanning dependencies of target openambit
[ 39%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/openambit.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 41%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/openambit.dir/mainwindow.cpp.o
[ 44%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/openambit.dir/devicemanager.cpp.o
[ 46%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/openambit.dir/settingsdialog.cpp.o
[ 48%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/openambit.dir/settings.cpp.o
[ 51%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/openambit.dir/logstore.cpp.o
[ 53%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/openambit.dir/logentry.cpp.o
[ 55%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/openambit.dir/udevlistener.cpp.o
[ 58%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/openambit.dir/confirmbetadialog.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/openambit.dir/single_application.cpp.o
[ 62%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/openambit.dir/movescount/movescount.cpp.o
[ 65%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/openambit.dir/movescount/movescountjson.cpp.o
/home/dustin/Desktop/openambit-0.2/src/openambit/movescount/movescountjson.cpp: In member function ‘int MovesCountJSON::generateLogData(LogEntry*, QByteArray&)’:
/home/dustin/Desktop/openambit-0.2/src/openambit/movescount/movescountjson.cpp:230:16: error: ‘class QJson::Serializer’ has no member named ‘setDoublePrecision’
/home/dustin/Desktop/openambit-0.2/src/openambit/movescount/movescountjson.cpp:231:16: error: ‘class QJson::Serializer’ has no member named ‘setIndentMode’
/home/dustin/Desktop/openambit-0.2/src/openambit/movescount/movescountjson.cpp:231:30: error: ‘IndentCompact’ is not a member of ‘QJson’
/home/dustin/Desktop/openambit-0.2/src/openambit/movescount/movescountjson.cpp:290:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘QJson::Serializer::serialize(QVariantMap&, bool*)’
/home/dustin/Desktop/openambit-0.2/src/openambit/movescount/movescountjson.cpp:290:47: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/qjson/serializer.h:50:10: note: void QJson::Serializer::serialize(const QVariant&, QIODevice*, bool*)
/usr/include/qjson/serializer.h:50:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘bool*’ to ‘QIODevice*’
/usr/include/qjson/serializer.h:62:16: note: QByteArray QJson::Serializer::serialize(const QVariant&)
/usr/include/qjson/serializer.h:62:16: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/openambit.dir/movescount/movescountjson.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/openambit.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
dustin@dustin:~/openambit-build$ sudo make install 
[  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/openambit.dir/movescount/movescountjson.cpp.o
/home/dustin/Desktop/openambit-0.2/src/openambit/movescount/movescountjson.cpp: In member function ‘int MovesCountJSON::generateLogData(LogEntry*, QByteArray&)’:
/home/dustin/Desktop/openambit-0.2/src/openambit/movescount/movescountjson.cpp:230:16: error: ‘class QJson::Serializer’ has no member named ‘setDoublePrecision’
/home/dustin/Desktop/openambit-0.2/src/openambit/movescount/movescountjson.cpp:231:16: error: ‘class QJson::Serializer’ has no member named ‘setIndentMode’
/home/dustin/Desktop/openambit-0.2/src/openambit/movescount/movescountjson.cpp:231:30: error: ‘IndentCompact’ is not a member of ‘QJson’
/home/dustin/Desktop/openambit-0.2/src/openambit/movescount/movescountjson.cpp:290:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘QJson::Serializer::serialize(QVariantMap&, bool*)’
/home/dustin/Desktop/openambit-0.2/src/openambit/movescount/movescountjson.cpp:290:47: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/qjson/serializer.h:50:10: note: void QJson::Serializer::serialize(const QVariant&, QIODevice*, bool*)
/usr/include/qjson/serializer.h:50:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘bool*’ to ‘QIODevice*’
/usr/include/qjson/serializer.h:62:16: note: QByteArray QJson::Serializer::serialize(const QVariant&)
/usr/include/qjson/serializer.h:62:16: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/openambit.dir/movescount/movescountjson.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/openambit.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am not sure what is going wrong.  I can post more of the output if needed as well.

Comment: Post the whole output, not just the last few lines.

Comment: @Gilles It is done.